# Perl: testing hash slice doesn't produce expected outcome

Tags: perl, hash

I have the following code:

```
if (defined(@hash{qw{value1 value2 value3}})){
    # code block
}
```

What I want to happen is for the code block to execute if either $hash{value1}, $hash{value2} or $hash{value3} is defined. However, what happens is that the code block executes if and only if $hash{value3} is defined:

```
$hash{value3}='yep, here!';
if (defined(@hash{qw{value1 value2 value3}})){
    print "yay!";
}
```

Output:

```
yay!
```

But:

```
$hash{value2}='yep, here!';
if (defined(@hash{qw{value1 value2 value3}})){
    print "yay!";
}
```

Output:

```
<nothing>
```

Why isn't this working right and what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[perldoc -f defined](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) doesn't mention hash slice, and warnings don't warn you about this, but what you want is,

```
if (grep defined, @hash{qw{value1 value2 value3}}) {
  # code block
}
```

as `defined()` forces scalar context, and *slices* in such case return last element.

```
use warnings;

sub context {
  print wantarray ? "LIST" : "SCALAR";
}

my $def = defined(context());
```

outputs `SCALAR`

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks. Filing under "why didn't I think of that?!"

Comment: The answer to "why isn't this working?" is that _[slices in scalar context return the last item of the slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices)_ (like [list literals](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#List-value-constructors)).

Comment: @pilcrow tnx for comment.